# MySQL Query, calculating data by column group

Tags: mysql, sql

i need some advices to procced result that i need,
this is the condition,
i have this data,

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g49C8.jpg)

the result i want is, i need to calculate the totalpointp and totalpointk with formula :

totalpointp = avg(ujnilaip - that **ujjenis H**)/2.5 + avg(ujnilaip - that **ujjenis M**)/3.5 + avg(ujnilaip - that **ujjenis S**)/4

totalpointk = avg(ujnilaik - that **ujjenis H**)/2.5 + avg(ujnilaik - that **ujjenis M**)/3.5 + avg(ujnilaik - that **ujjenis S**)/4

im confused with the query, the lastest query i tried :

any advice will be helpful, thanks in advance

> SELECT ujsiswa,
>   AVG(ujnilaip) AS totalnilaip,
>   AVG(ujnilaik) AS
>   totalnilaik 
>   FROM ujian GROUP BY ujmp;

Comment: Your query does not make logical sense, because you are grouping by only two columns but selecting many non aggregate columns.

Comment: im sorry that was my best try, the other columns are relationship things, maybe we can skip it, and do the clean query for this case, thank you

Comment: this is the kind of result i want, but the totalnilaip and totalnilaik are wrong value base on the formula.
http://imgur.com/OWlhRZ8

Comment: Show us a _minimal_ question with sample input and output.  As of now, you have just dumped a screenshot with a broken ambiguous query.

Comment: the input is on the question post.
simple output i want is http://imgur.com/J7sY8dE
the question is : how can i get the correct value of totalnilaip and totalnilaik based on the formula i asked on the question post?